simple confusion regarding integration by parts for matrices.
Let $A(t)$ be a square matrix that depends on a real parameter $t$. I'm interested in the following 2-fold integral,
\begin{equation}
I = \int_0^T dt A(t) (\int_0^t ds A(s)). 
\end{equation} Using integration by parts, the above equation is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
I = (\int A(t))(\int_0^t ds A(s))|_0^T - \int_0^T dt (\int A(t)) A(t). 
\end{equation} From this, it seems like if $\int_0^t ds A(s) = \int A(t)$, then we have
\begin{equation}
I = \frac{1}{2}(\int A(t))(\int_0^t ds A(s))|_0^T = \frac{1}{2}(\int_0^t ds A(s)))^2|_0^T. 
\end{equation} This seems like a very weird conclusion to me. What am I missing? Is the assumption ($\int_0^t ds A(s) = \int A(t)$) something cannot be satisfied?

If you replace $A(t)$ with a function $f(t)$ then the integral you have written is $I=\int_0^T F(t) dF(t)$ where $F(t)=\int_0^t f(s) ds$. Then $I=\frac{1}{2}F(T)^2 $; however if $F(t)=\int_0^t A(t) dt$ then $dF(t)^2=A(t)F(t)dt+F(t)A(t)dt$. If $F(t)A(t)=A(t)F(t)$ then you get the same result.

$$
F(t)=\left[\begin{matrix}t & \frac{t^{2}}{2}\\frac{t^{3}}{3} & - \frac{t^{4}}{4}\end{matrix}\right]
$$
$$
A(t)=\left[\begin{matrix}1 & t\t^{2} & - t^{3}\end{matrix}\right]
$$
$$
F(t)A(t)=
\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{t^{4}}{2} + t & - \frac{t^{5}}{2} + t^{2}\- \frac{t^{6}}{4} + \frac{t^{3}}{3} & \frac{t^{7}}{4} + \frac{t^{4}}{3}\end{matrix}\right]
$$
$$
A(t)F(t)=
\left[\begin{matrix}\frac{t^{4}}{3} + t & - \frac{t^{5}}{4} + \frac{t^{2}}{2}\- \frac{t^{6}}{3} + t^{3} & \frac{t^{7}}{4} + \frac{t^{4}}{2}\end{matrix}\right]
$$

Your issue is that you are trying to commute matrices that do not necessarily commute. There's a few different ways to approach this problem; I will use the technique you took, but I will explicitly write out integrals (meaning that $\int A(t)dt$ needs bounds)
We start with
$$
I=\int_0^TA(t)\int_0^tA(s)\,ds\,dt=\int_0^T\left(A(t)\right)\left(\int_0^tA(s)\,ds\right)\,dt
$$
which, as you have noticed, is an integral of a product of two functions of $t$. To integrate by parts, we want to give an explicit representation for the antiderivative of $A(t)$ as to not confuse ourselves. The one that I will pick, following along with our domain of integration, will be
$$
B(t)=\int_0^tA(s)\,ds\implies B'(t)=A(t)
$$
so our original integral can actually be written as
$$
I=\int_0^TA(t)B(t)\,dt
$$
Now, integrating by parts and remembering that matrices do not commute,
$$
I=B(t)B(t)\,ds\Big|_{t=0}^{t=T}-\int_0^TB(t)A(t)\,dt
$$
Noting that $B(0)=0$,
$$
I=\int_0^TA(t)B(t)\,dt=B(T)B(T)-\int_0^TB(t)A(t)\,dt
$$
This, notably, does nothing to evaluate $I$; it simply rebrands the integral in terms of how the two matrices commute. In general, we cannot obtain an expression for $I$ without knowing more details about $A$, but this is how the integration by parts would play out.

Very clear! Thanks! One minor point: in your second equation, you meant by $\int_0^t A(s)ds$ (instead of dt), right?
